# Bootstrap Style sheet could not rendering when put on style sheet to the bundleConfig in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, assets

I have tried to put on Bootstrap stylesheet in `bundleConfig` for mvc4 project but that stylesheet could not rendering when I view my source, so I'm getting design issues. My code following:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

My bundleConfig Code below

> public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
>
> ```
>     {
>         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
>                     "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
>
>         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
>                     "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
>
>         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
>                     "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
>                     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
>
>         // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
>         // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
>         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
>                     "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
>         bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
>         bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
>                     "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css",
>                     "~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" ));
>         bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/assets").Include(
>                                 "~/assets/css/headers/header1.css",
>                                 "~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css",
>                                 "~/assets/css/style_responsive.css",
>                                 "~/assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
>                                 "~/assets/plugins/parallax-slider/css/parallax-slider.css",
>                                 "~/assets/style.css"));
>         BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
>           }
> ```

Could you please help me?

Comment: please add your bundleCongif's code

Comment: One issue, is that jQuery needs to be loaded before bootstrap.min.js

Comment: helo Elvin Arzumanoğlu, I have add my bundleCongif's code

Answer (score 1):

By default the minified scripts are ignored. So you have two options :

1. Remove the .min from the bootstrap css file names.
2. Clear the IgnoreList.

Doing one of those should be enough.